# Error in Google Places API request

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, get, google-api

I'm making a get request to google places API using jQuery and I'm getting a successful response, but the data is not being displayed on my page. This is the code I'm using to send the request, and I've included 2 pictures of of what the dev tools are showing me.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJh4vtq-kQsYkRET-Imf6RsuA&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#over_map").text(data.formatted_address);
        }
    });
});
```

Dev tools screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try  `dataType: 'json'` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google Places place details API page](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details), it looks like the server does not support JSONP. Additionally, the API page has this to say:

> The Google Places API Web Service is for use in server applications. If you're building a client-side application, take a look at the [Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/) and the [Places Library in the Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/).

This leads me to believe that CORS headers will probably not be set, because Google is expecting you to use this API on the server side, and not on the client side.

My recommendation would be to try changing `dataType: 'jsonp',` to `dataType: 'json',` in your AJAX request, and if that causes the browser to throw an origin error, then you will need to work out a server-side solution instead of your current client-side one.

Comment: I'm also getting the origin error whilst trying to use AJAX / JSON. What would a server-side solution look like?

Comment: @user2586455 Any server-side language should be able to perform the request normally  without any fuss.